# Probability measure of a communication mechanism

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, game-theory, information-theory, economics

The following definition is from [this paper in page 72](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.685.4204&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

$\textit{Definition:}$ A communication mechanism is a triple $\mathfrak{C}=((T_i)_i, (Y_i)_i , l )$, where $T_i$ is $i's$ finite set of messages, $Y_i$ is $i's$ finite set of signals, and $l: T\to \Delta(Y)$ is the signal function. When $t$ is the profile of messages sent by the players, $y\in Y$ is drawn according to $l(t)$ and player $i$ is informed of $y_i$. $\mathfrak{T}_i=\Delta(T_i)$ represents the set of mixed messages for player $i$ and $l$ is extended to $\mathfrak{T}$ by $l(\tau)( y)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau} l(t)( y)$.

$\textit{Question 1:}$ What is this $\tau$ probability measure and why is this defined in this way, namely what is the intuition behind this? Apparently, the way that the communication mechanism is defined comes from the measure theory, but how did he end up with the $l$ function defined under a $\tau$ probability measure?

$\textit{Question 2:}$ What is the meaning of $l(t)(y)$, does this mean $l(t,y)$? I have never seen this symbolism $l(t)(y)$ again.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe if we could provide an example in this definition as in this post 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252029/probability-measure-and-conditional-probability-intuition-and-notation-problem/4252068?noredirect=1#comment8840559_4252068

it would be better to understand it!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the intuition is that all players send messages, represented by a vector $t$. Now those messages are converted into a signal each player receives. This signal can be random, so we are assuming it is sampled from a distribution which depends on $t$. Now $\tau$ is a mixed message, that means a distribution on $T$. The idea is, that it can make sense for us as a player to randomize our choices (in this case we chose to send a signal).

Comment: I think $l(\tau)(y)=E_{\tau}l(t)(y)$ is just a sort of definition. We are computing the probability of the signal $y$ if we send a mixed message $\tau$.

Comment: The last word of my first comment should be "message".

Comment: @GrafZahl I understand all these, but my problem is why he defines $l(\tau)(y)$ in this way? I understand that it is an estimation after all because whatever player $i$ knows is according to a probability which comes from this $l$ now. When I read this in first place I thought it was something like a conditional probability, I will know $y$ given that I already know $\tau$, because the latter is the message that $i$ sends to the mechanism. Then I thought that is something like a product of $l(\tau)$ with $y$ but since $l:T\to\Delta(Y)$ maybe it is a conditional probability..

Comment: I give up :P .... why is this $l(\tau)(y)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau}l(t)(y)$, this $\tau$ serves as a probability measure as well...

Comment: I would think $l(\tau)(y)$ is defined as new object, which I would paraphrase as the probability of $y$ given the mixed message $\tau$. This comes close to your intuition, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly, because the signal function says, give me a message, whatever this message is, maybe it is $t\in T$ or $\tau\in \mathcal{T}$, but I in return the mechanism will give you a signal in the simplex of $Y$ (namely in $\Delta(Y)$) so this $l()$ needs to be a probability distribution... I think

Comment: Exactly. The way it is defined, $l(\tau)$ is just a probability depending on the mixed message.

Comment: Good, I need to build an example now, to make the exercise for me...you know...then I will have understand this totally....

Comment: @GrafZahl I really appreciate your help...

Comment: Game theory is a nice topic. Maybe start by considering two players, each with two possible messages. In a next step, take probabilities for possible signals $y$ depending on each message (Sp $l(t)$ should be a distribution on $Y$). Then look what happens if you chose randomized messages.

Comment: @GrafZahl   Exactly... by $S_p l(t)$ you denote the distribution?

Comment: Typo, no idea where that comes from ^^just $l(t)$

Comment: :D I got so confused ahaahahahaha.... I said go back to the kindergarten ...

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: No worries...your help was so precious!