# Probability measure and conditional probability intuition and notation problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, game-theory, computational-mathematics

I have the following definition in probability theory from a paper in game theory.

$\textit{Definition:}$ Suppose that $(X^i)_{i=1}^n$, where $i=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $n<+\infty$, is a collection of finite sets. Define the set $\mathcal{A}=(X,\mu)$, where $X=\Pi_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $\mu$ is the probabolity measure over $X$. When $x\in X$ is drawn according to $\mu$, then every palyer $i$ is informed about the coordinate $x^i$. Even further for every $x^i$ such that $\mu(x^i)>0$, then $p(x^i)\in\Delta(X^{-i})$ denotes the conditional probability of $\mu$ given $x^i$ over $X^{-i}$:
$$p(x^i)(x^{-i})=\mu(x^{-i}|x^i)=\frac{\mu(x^i,x^{-i})}{\mu(x^i)}$$

Also, note that $\mu(x^i)$ stands for $\mu(x^i\times X^{-i})$.

I face difficulty in understanding the notation and I have the following questions:

1. Is the probability measure $\mu$ defined as follows:

$$\mu:X\to \Delta(X)\subset [0,1]^ n$$

2. I strugle to understand the last proposition ''Even further...stands for $\mu(x^i\times X^{-i})$''. What is the intuition and how this transition occurs from $\mu$ to $p$?

If it would be simple to provide an example according to the definition I would appreciate this. For instance lets suppose that n=3, so $X=X^1\times X^2\times X^3= \{a,b\}\times\{z,y\}\times\{u,v\}$, and then $x=(\underbrace{a}_{x^1},\underbrace{z}_{x^1},\underbrace{u}_{x^1})$, what does it mean that $\mu(x^2)>0$ according to the definition above? Can anybody build an example?

Comment: Regarding your first question. It reads as $\mu:\mathcal{P}(X)\to [0,1]$ since $(X,\mu)$ is a probability space.

Comment: @GrafZahl I do not think this is the case and let me explain you why. It says that $\mu$ is defined over $X$ but $X$ is the Cartesian product of the sets $X^1, X^2,...,X^n$, so the domain it is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ according to you which is right because it is the power set, but the co-domain can not be $[0,1]$. $\mu$ does not give back a simple number, but a probability distribution according to the input that you took from $X$

Comment: This is why I ask for an example...if someone can think about this

Comment: I would assume that's the usual abuse of notation in game theory. I will write an answer.

Comment: @GrafZahl Ok take your time to write a clear answer...thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X_1=\{a_1,b_1\}$, $X_2=\{a_2,b_2\}$ and $X_3=\{a_3,b_3\}$. Then $X=\{a_1,b_1\}\times\{a_2,b_2\}\times \{a_3,b_3\}$. Consider following probability on $X$:

- $\mu(\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\})=\mu(\{(b_1,b_2,b_3)\})=\frac{1}{5}.$
- $\mu(\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\})=\frac{1}{10}$ for all other $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in X$.

Now $X^{-i}=\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nX_i$, in our case $X^{-1}=X_2\times X_3$, $X^{-2}=X_1\times X_3$ and $X^{-3}=X_1\times X_2$. This yields the first abuse of notation. For example, by $(a_2,X^{-2})$ we usually denote the set $\{(x_1,a_2,x_3)\in X:\ (x_1,x_3)\in X^{-2}\}$. I hope this meets your understanding so far.

If we now want to consider conditional probabilities, we could think of the probability of $x_1=a_1$ and $x_3=a_3$ if we know $x_2=a_2$. This is indeed $\mu(\{(a_1,x_2,a_3):\ x_2\in X_2\} |\{(x_1,a_2,x_3):\ (x_1,x_3)\in X^{-2}\} )$. Using the definition of conditioned probability yields, that this equals $\mu(\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\})/\mu((a_2,X^{-2}))=\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{5}+3\cdot\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{2}{5}$.

If $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, the same notational abuse as above lets us write $a=(a_2,a^{-2})$ with $a^{-2}=(a_1,a_3)$ and by $p(a_2)(a^{-2})$ we obtain a far nicer way of writing the conditional probability we just derived.

I hope those conventions I used make sense for your applications.

Comment: I think they make sense, but i need some time to make an example or two on my own...you know by combining together game theory and probability theory...it is a little tricky as I see, not so difficult but tricky....Thanks, I will endorse your answer when i finish my studying later in the day...can i go one with a similar question?

Comment: Take your time :) And of course you can ask a follow up.

Comment: Can you check this for a moment?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220395/probability-measure-of-a-communication-mechanism

Comment: it's an older post of mine

Comment: ok I think your answer meets my standards, I want only one clarification here, this notation $p(x^i)(x^{-i})$ is something that I am not aware of in game theory notation...is it standard or it has to do with the way that the author writes?

Comment: I haven't seen it before, but I think if you are meeting some other notation you should get the meaning from the context.

Comment: ok my question is the following
- $\mu(\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\})=\mu(\{(b_1,b_2,b_3)\})=\mu(\{(c_1,c_2,c_3)\})=\frac{2}{9}.$
- $\mu(\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\})=\frac{1}{18}$ for all other $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in X$.
This vector $\{(c_1,c_2,c_3)\}$ does not belong to some of the $X^i$'s

Comment: Well my question here is more general, how did you thought about building the probability measure $\mu$? and I think we are done

Comment: Yep, that was a mistake, I hope it's fixed.

Comment: Ok which was your thought to define $\mu$ in this way? forget the mistake...its fixed now, but how did you make think to make this?

Comment: I didn't want it to be a uniform distribution so I chose some events and gave them a higher probability. The choice is up to you here, in the end, it just has to ad up to 1. Write all your possible outcomes down and then think of how to assert probabilities to each outcome.

Comment: Tell me something how many elements has the powerset?, is it $2^{|?|}$?

Comment: In general $|X_1\times \dots \times X_n|=|X_1|\cdot \dots \cdot |X_n|$, so indeed, the number of elements of $X$ here is $2^3$ and for power sets its the corresponding power.

Comment: So the power set has $2^{|2\times 2\times 2|}=2^8$ elements

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? what is $X_1^3$? I am confused :P

Comment: Shoot, It' late for me. I better rest. You are totally right, I confused power set and the cartesian power.

Comment: Thanks for every help. Have a good rest!